# Closing all previously opened editors at the time of Eclipse launch

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have designed an Eclipse plugin. Eclipse has a feature that if the workbench is closed with some open editors, then next time Eclipse is launched all the editors opened in the previous session remain in the open state.

My requirement is to close all the open editors based on the previous session at the time Eclipse is launched. In one of the classes of plugin designed, I added following piece of code

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();
for (IWorkbenchWindow iWorkbenchWindow : windows) {
  if (iWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage() != null) {
    break;
  }
  iWorkbenchWindow.close();
}
```

This code is closing the editors at the time of launching. but it also throws an exception:

```
"Unable to read workbench state. Workbench UI layout will be reset.
java.lang.NullPointerException".
```

Request you to let me know where am I wrong.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/703373/

I quote

```
On 27.07.2011 12:43, newbie wrote:
> Hi,
> I have created an eclipse plugin.. From the eclipse workbench, i want 
> to close all the open editors on some change event in a combo box 
> located on the tools panel.. I want to perform an exactly similar 
> action which is achieved by right click an editor and selec "Close 
> All" action. Can you please help me with the java code or eclipse 
> api's to achieve that?

org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage.closeAllEditors(boolean)

Dani
>
> Thanks
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. My previous post and this post, these are two separate issues. In the current post i want to close all editors before eclipse is launched. As i said, i am able to close the editors, but i get an exception as well. I think the reason behind that is eclipse somewhere saves the information of all opened editors and since the editors are closed before launching, when the launch happens, workbench state is not getting set properly. I am looking for an answer to get rid of that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but I guess you perform your code too soon in the Eclipse startup sequence...

If you were doing an RCP application, you should try to add the code to `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup()`... but you're not...

For the IDE it seems to be quite a bit more difficult, as there are no hook (AFAICS) that allows you to execute your code after the IDE is fully loaded.

Alternatively add a listener to all `IWorkbenchWindows` that monitors `partOpened` events, and close the editors here...